# referring to a previous record in MS access query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a very Hard Time referring to a previous record in MS access query.
I know about the Dlockup but the problem is:
I want to refer to a previous record in the transaction table using [TransactionID] field, BUT transactions in that table is belong to many Customers in the Customers table.
So if I just ask for a previous record in the transaction table using the [TransactionID] field it will just give me the previous record even if it belongs to another customer and that what I don't want.
I use this  right now

```
Expr1: DLookUp("[TheFieldThatIWantItsPreviousValue]",
"TheQueryThatHavingTheTwoTablesTogether","[TransactionID]=" & [TransactionID]-1)
```

But I don't know how to add a part that say do that only if the previous record belongs to the same [CustomerID]?!
Like I want something like:

```
Expr1: DLookUp("[TheFieldThatIWantItsPreviousValue]",
"TheQueryThatHavingTheTwoTablesTogether","[TransactionID]=" & [TransactionID]-1) where [CutomerID] = [CutomerID]
```

Or Like

```
Expr1: DLookUp("[TheFieldThatIWantItsPreviousValue]",
"TheQueryThatHavingTheTwoTablesTogether","[TransactionID]=" & [TransactionID]-1 and [CutomerID] = [CutomerID])
```

I Appreciate your help very much,
Thank you in advance,
David.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the maximum TransactionID belonging to that customer, that is lower than the current one:

```
DMax("TransactionID", "TransactionTable", 
     "CustomerID = " & CustomerID & " AND TransactionID < " & [TransactionID])
```

Then feed that result into your original DLookUp call:

```
DLookUp("TheFieldThatIWantItsPreviousValue]", "TheQuryThatHavingTheTwoTablesTogether", 
    "[TransactionID]=" & DMax(... see above ...))
```