# Is there a way in MS Access to calculate based on previous record?

Tags: excel, database, ms-access

Like in title is there a way in MS Access to calculate field based on current and previous record?
Overall i want to migrate my Excel file to Access because of amount of data, but i stuck on "translating" formulas to Access.

I have a table, log-like data.
User|Date|Hour
At the end of the tabel i have few columns with calculation with I want to move to access:
T1 `=IF(U3=U2;(V3+W3)-(V2+W2);"")`
T2 `=IFERROR(IF(HOUR(Z3)>=4;"";Z3);"")`
T3 `=IF(AA3="";"";IF((AA3*24)>12;0;AA3))`

Screenshot of the actual table. [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PfYY.png)

Is there a way to do something similar in Access?

Comment: In Access, you will do that in a query having a _subquery_ for the previous record and another subquery for the next record.

Comment: Uh, I don't have much experience with using subquery. Do you mind giving an example how to subquery for previous record?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64113037/selecting-additional-data-values-to-display-as-column-in-query-or-in-form/64114074#64114074) is an example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HOW TO SELECT PREVIOUS ROW VALUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067672/how-to-select-previous-row-value). Also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267204/referring-to-a-previous-record-in-ms-access-query and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629523/access-get-value-from-previous-record and http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html.